# the hopper is connected to the chest but the items still won't go into the chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: i'm trying to make the items in the hopper go into the chest]

i'm playing an adventure map, and i'm supposed to put an item into the hopper so it goes into the chest, but it isn't going in, so i turned to ceative to fix it, but i cant. i didnt include this in the picture, but there is a hopper on top of the hopper you see in the picture

Answer (score 2):

Hoppers being powered by redstone become disabled, and will no longer transfer items.

There appears to be a piece of powered redstone dust to the right side of your screenshot which is powering the hopper. Presumably the adventure map has some way to turn this redstone power off.

Comment: This would be my guess as well

Comment: But the redstone dust's direction is away from the hopper, and it's powering a block which doesn't activate the hopper either.

Comment: @JimJones It looks like a dot of redstone dust to me, which will activate the hopper.